# WS02 Greg 5.2.x SVN-Based Deployment Synchronizer

Tags: svn, wso2, wso2-governance-registry

I have a cluster of Greg server, and I was trying to implement the SVN 
I have the same setup un those machines for the ESB cluster and it works fine.
With Greg nothing at all: no error, no logs entries: it looks like it just ignore che SVN conf in carbon.xml

```
<DeploymentSynchronizer>
        <Enabled>true</Enabled>
        <AutoCommit>true</AutoCommit>
        <AutoCheckout>true</AutoCheckout>
        <RepositoryType>svn</RepositoryType>
        <SvnUrl>svn://mySVN/greg_clust/</SvnUrl>
        <SvnUser>wso2</SvnUser>
        <SvnPassword>2osw</SvnPassword>
        <SvnUrlAppendTenantId>true</SvnUrlAppendTenantId>
</DeploymentSynchronizer>
```

The repo is fine, I can co and commit from the command line, the lib are the same that I use on the ESB: yet no joy at all.

Maybe it's a silly question, but does Greg support SVN Deployment ?
My understanding was all carbon prods should support it

Comment: Did you follow the following guide when configuring the deployment synchronizer? https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+SVN-Based+Deployment+Synchronizer

Comment: @madawa yes
As I said all my 8 ESB clusters (1mgt 2node) are working fine.
Only the GREG seem to ignore the deployment synchronizer
Do you know if it is supported in GREG ?

Comment: @Danieli could you please explain the usecase of doing this. ?

Comment: @thusharaK we deploy carbonapps in a cluster if GREG 5.2.0
My understanding was I should sync all nodes via SVN, or I'm missing something here ?
Thank you in advance

Comment: @massimo-danieli If you are adding resources to the registry using those CApps, DepSync is not necessary to have, and resources added to the registry will be automatically appeared in other nodes.